# Very simple variable increment then database update javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am looking for a very simple process to record a click to an element then to update a database with that number.

For example a page is displayed then the variable is incremented when a click is made within that element. It only needs to record 1 click so a 0/1 variable is fine but when the zero changes to a 1 it needs to be recorded on the database.

Any simple way to do this? I am assuming it would be ajax but not too hot with that. I would need to also pass the ID of the row to update on the DB. Any help is appreciated :)

It really needs to happen in the background with the only interaction being the click on the element that holds the page so no page refresh. I have a good idea of what i want but the coding part in Javascript/Ajax eludes me. Basically i need to set up a listener for the click or an onclick to the element which will then fire up ajax to send a single variable (the id in the database) which will update the row in the db.

```
so for example

<div id="page" onclick="updateclick()">
Page content
</div>

<script>
function updateclick() {
var click = "1";
ajax part to send the variable $db_id to a seperate php file so the DB can 
be updated
}
</script>
```

Something like this.

Comment: Can you show something that you've tried? You are on the right path in regards to using AJAX (depending on the use case)... perhaps you can couple that with `data` attributes in your html tags, which are buffered from PHP :)

Comment: AJAX is kinda irrelevant here - it's useful if you don't want the page to reload when they click the button, but that may not be needed. Fundamentally, you just need to fire off some sort of request (AJAX, simple <form>, even just a link) when they click it and make a database query on the PHP side. Start and come back with specific questions - we can't really answer vague "help me?" questions here.